# Maximal and Prime Ideal in Z

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ the following conditions on a nonzero ideal $I$ are equivalent: (i) $I$ is prime; (ii) $I$ is maximal; (iii) $I=(p)$ with $p$ prime.

Comment: Do you know a characterization of all the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I know that the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $n\mathbb{Z}=(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\mathbb{Z}/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: I do not understand how is this related to the question....

Comment: Yes this is related. One needs to see that $\mathbb{Z}/I$ for any ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite integral domain. And a finite integral domain is a...?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik This is related, when is Z/I a field... then you already get (i) if and only if (iii).

Comment: May be.. It is just my personal feeling that it could have been "hinted " better... Nothing serious....

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Principal Ideal Domain (PID).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**
**|.** Try to show that every non-zero ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is generated by an element in the ideal with minimal absolute value.
**||.** Show that an ideal $(n)$ is prime iff $n$ is prime iff the ideal is maximal.
Hope this helps.